# ¿Cómo puedo añadir (click) a un botón que previamente fue generado con "document.createElement" en Angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular12, setattribute

Estoy aprendiendo Angular por mi mismo y tengo este problema. Yo genero con un botón un div para contener un texto y un botón eliminar, y a el botón eliminar que está dentro de el div contenedor quiero que tenga (click) para que ejecute mi función deleteDiv(){}.

Con esto genero el div para contener el texto y el botón eliminar.

```
const prin = document.createElement("div");
      prin.setAttribute('style',
        ` display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;`);
      prin.setAttribute('id', `prin1`);
      const prin1 = document.getElementById('pro1');
      prin1?.appendChild(prin);
      const el = document.createElement("div");
      el.setAttribute('style',
        ` height: 40px;
          width: 100%; 
          padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px; 
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;`);
      el.setAttribute('id', `boxpro`);
      const pro1 = document.getElementById('prin1');
      pro1?.appendChild(el);
```

Con esto genero el texto, el cual es el nombre de un producto.

```
      pp1 = document.createElement("p");
      pp1.textContent = `Arroz Roa x ` + this.valor + ``;
      pp1.setAttribute('style', `font-size: 12px;`);
      const boxpro = document.getElementById("boxpro");
      boxpro?.appendChild(pp1);
```

y con esto intento generar el botón eliminar, sé que no se puede hacer "setAttribute('(click)', 'deleteDiv()')", pero es para que se entienda.

```
      const a_icono = document.createElement("a");
      a_icono.setAttribute('id', `aicono`); 
      a_icono.setAttribute('(click)', `deleteDiv()`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale esto te podria ayudar, cambiaremos el "**setAttribute**" por un "**addEventListener**" y ahí escucharemos el "**click**" y configuraremos las acciones a ejecutar:

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
const a_icono = document.createElement('a'); //aquí puede ser 'button' o 'a'
a_icono.textContent = 'x';
a_icono.setAttribute('id', `aicono`);

a_icono.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Actions to execute'));
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo corriendo aquí:

https://codepen.io/jonas_dev/pen/ZEoavEa?editors=1111

Comment: Me solucionaste la vida, funciona perfecto. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Genial, me alegra mucho! happy coding (: